# Why does Java convert \n\r to \\n\\r when reading them from DB

Tags: java, newline, h2, carriage-return

I have some text in the database(**H2**) as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
ID  |       User     |            Properties           |
--------------------------------------------------------
1   |       Oli      |     age=23\n\rgender=MALE\n\r   |
--------------------------------------------------------
2   |       Umpa     |     age=23\n\rjob=STUDENT\n\r   |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

When I query these rows in my application, Java converts all `\n\r` characters `to \\n\\r`and it means there aren't any **LF** and **CR** characters in the final string in my application.

Finally, I have replaced **\n\r** characters by **\n\r** in the program and the problem was solved. (`queried_column.replace("\\n\\r","\r\n")`)

Now, my question is why Java has this behavior?

Comment: Can you post the code that is used to retrieve the data from the database? That would most likely help.

Comment: It looks like your database string contains the literal characters ```\``` followed by `n`, and Java is correctly producing two separate characters instead of intepreting that as the new-line character ```\n```. If you want *backslash-followed-by-n* in your string to be converted to `\n`, then `replace` is a reasonable way of doing it.

Comment: @thg I read it simply by `Hibernate` and `JPA` and mapping the column is :     @Column(length = 2000, name = "Properties")
               private String parameters;

Comment: You can use `STRINGDECODE()` to convert them back into the real line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the text in your database doesn't contain **LF** or **CR** characters, it contains `\` characters, `n` characters and `r` characters. So Java isn't converting anything, it gives you **exactly** the text from the database.

Your solution to un-escape those special characters is correct.

Comment: I would not go as far as to say the solution is correct.

The best solution would be to correctly input the data in the database to contain proper LF and CR characters.

Comment: @Remcoder Imho that's out of the scope of this question. And that other, potentially better, solutions exist, doesn't mean this one is incorrect. It might not be preferred, but it's still correct. Anyways, feel free to add your own answer, that's what this community is for :)

Comment: @MaxVollmer Thank for your reply. I know that the text in my database doesn't have LF or CR characters, and I'm looking up for its reasons. In others words, is there any way which I'm not forced to replace those characters?

Comment: @MJM That would be a different question and out of scope of Java/programming (depending where those values come from). It's a database related question. I'd recommend searching for solutions and if you can't find one, ask a new question. If it's not programming related on https://dba.stackexchange.com/